# Dynamically mapping an array of objects to table row

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to map an array of objects to table rows in React. I've tried countless suggestions on this site but nothing seems to render in the end.

I'm getting the array data from the db on `componentWillMount` as so:

```
         componentWillMount(){
         db.collection("games")
         .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot){
             querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
                 games.push(doc.data())
             });
             console.log(games);
         })
      }
```

The data is loading properly as seen in `games`. `games` is declared as a global variable outside the react class.

So far I've tried mapping over the array like this:

```
renderRow = () => {
    games.map(function(val, i){
        return(
            <tr>
                <td key={i}>
                    {val.name}
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    })
}
```

And then rendering it in the table like so:

```
            <table className="ui inverted table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Lobby name</th>
                        <th>Players</th>
                        <th>Mode</th>
                        <th>Difficulty</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   {this.renderRow()}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

But nothing seems to render. I'm not sure if i'm not mapping over it properly, or perhaps it's rendering the table values before the array is loaded with data. Any thoughts on this?

Edit: `console.log(games)` gives this:

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
currentPlayers: 1
difficulty: ""
gameMode: "family"
host: "###########"
name: "Testing new reset"
players:
player: "###########"
__proto__: Object
timestamp: 1550704627051
__proto__: Object
1: {currentPlayers: 1, difficulty: "heroic", gameMode: "experienced", host: "", name: "Testtest", …}
2: {currentPlayers: 1, difficulty: "veteren", gameMode: "experienced", host: "", name: "Flashpoint experts only!", …}
```

Comment: First welcome to the community, although you've joined over a year ago.  Your question was worded well and so, thank you for that.  Just to let you know, you can build a working snippet using Babel, React, and JSX.

Comment: @mike means not here on Stack Overflow, but on some external site.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the code snippet on StackOverflow is capable of rendering React & Babel and performing the JSX transpiling.  However, it may be limited to web interfaces, so if you're using a mobile device the app interface may not allow for it.  Also, if browsing from a mobile browser, you may have to put it in desktop mode depending on the device.

Comment: @Mike I know, but pasting all the code here on snippets? Would be a long one, with all the data etc... But yeah, a "working" example would be easier to play with

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes that is true, I've used it for simple things like this where it wasn't too bad, though.  Still the lengthy question/example is a real possibility.  A person may have to hide it on initial load and require readers to expand it.  I think having the snippet yields more participation from the community as it's easier to *copy to answer* than to think about about and copy/paste or type up a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not returning anything in renderRow so need to add return before games.map

Change

```
   renderRow = () => {
        games.map(function(val, i){
            return(
               <tr>
                  <td key={i}>
                      {val.name}
                  </td>
               </tr>
            )
        })
   }
```

To

```
  renderRow = () => {
        return games.map(function(val, i){
            return(
               <tr>
                  <td key={i}>
                      {val.name}
                  </td>
               </tr>
            )
        })
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it still doesn't render anything, no errors in console either. I'm wondering if this is something else that's causing this now.

Comment: @sags95 can you do console.log(games) and share the output

Comment: @sags95 no do console.log in render and share the output

Comment: nvm this actually did seem to fix the issue. But the rows only render when I click on a button that triggers a modal. It's an odd issue but i'll have to investigate that further.

Comment: @sags95 please upvote and accept the answer if it resolves your issue

Answer (score 1):

If the function you are calling in `componentWillMount` to fetch the games is asynchronous it may be that your React component renders before your data is fetched.

You should try to set the state of the component when the `games` array is fetched and the React will re-render the component.

eg.

```
class Games extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      games: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    db.collection("games")
      .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
        let gamesArray = []
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
          gamesArray.push(doc.data())
        });
        this.setState({ games: gamesArray })
      })
  }

  renderRow = () => {
    return this.state.games.map(function (val, i) {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td key={i}>
            {val.name}
          </td>
        </tr>
      )
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="ui inverted table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Lobby name</th>
            <th>Players</th>
            <th>Mode</th>
            <th>Difficulty</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.renderRow()}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}
```